# Do we hear anything special when the beat frequency is in audible range, but the sounds producing the beats are not?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference, superposition, perception

When the beat frequency is very low, we hear periodic maxima and minima.
Our ear cannot perceive a on-off like sound when its frequency is more than 10 Hz.
So, beat frequency in audible range will not appear like a sound going on and off.
Do we perceive any special when the beat frequency  is in the audible range (20 to 20000 Hz) ?
(Let us assume that we can perceive every sound whose frequency is in the audible range)

Comment: Those of use who have poor pitch use beating amplitudes to tune our guitars.

Comment: There is a problem in Hewitt's book, stating that one would hear beats between two ultrasound sources at 100 kHz and 102 kHz. Of course, this was not based on observation.

Comment: @Pieter: and how do you know this was not based on observation? [Consider this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_from_ultrasound#HyperSonic_Sound).

Comment: @PeterShor Nonlinearities and very high levels of ultrasound (over 100 dB) are needed to create anything audible. (I have tried with our 41 kHz piezotransducers, I can see the beats with a microphone on an oscilloscope, but do not hear anything. None of my students either.)

Comment: @Pieter: so clearly our ears are not non-linear enough.  Interesting.

Comment: I am voting to close because the same question has been posted later and has attracted better answers, although this question was posted first and is much clearer than the other question was before editing.